# css overflow auto for dynamically added columns

Tags: css

The table, inner div, and the fieldset expand out of the outer div when the no. of cols increase.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fgj6Y/

1. The Outer div, fieldset and the inner div widths should be intact.
2. The td's should have a fixed width.
3. The overflowing cols should be hidden & can be viewed by scrolling.

I am having a hard time acheiving this. Do not want to set fixed widths as that doesnt seem a good way for me. Tried overflow, whitespace props for all/each containers.

```
<div style="border:1px solid gray;padding:1%">
        <fieldset style="border:1px solid red;border-radius:5px">
                <div style="overflow-x:auto;border:1px solid green">
                        <table width="100%" border="1" bordercolor="blue">
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Casual Leave</td>
                                        <td>AnnualLeave</td>
                                        <td>SickLeave</td>
                                        <td>Compassionate Leave</td>
                                        <td>Maternity Leave</td>
                                        <td>Another Leave</td>
                                        <td>Some Other Leave</td>
<td>Casual Leave</td>
                                        <td>AnnualLeave</td>
                                        <td>SickLeave</td>
                                        <td>Compassionate Leave</td>
                                        <td>Maternity Leave</td>
                                        <td>Another Leave</td>
                                        <td>Some Other Leave</td>

                                <tr>
                        </table>
                </div>
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want to set `overflow-x` for the outer div?

```
<div style="border:1px solid gray;padding:1%; overflow-x: auto;">
    <fieldset style="border:1px solid red;border-radius:5px">
        ...
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fgj6Y/3/

***Important note:*** Avoid *inline* styles.

Comment: Thank you but the scroll should be for the inner div and not the outer. Exclusive for the table scroll.

Comment: Then it is impossible. The inner div won't have scrollbar until it has fixed width. It's the ultimate condition.

Comment: oh :( `<div style="overflow-x:hidden"> <fieldset style="max-width:1100px"> <div style="overflow-x:hidden;max-width:1100px">`...The 1100px looks good on current screen. But wouldnt this be a contingency. How should I deal with smaller/bigger screens and if cols inc more than 1100 px

Comment: Well, I think you should decide what should be the width of your website and set the `.inner` width accordingly. Most desktop websites are somewhere about `980px`. If you want a responsive design - there are lots of techniques out there, but that subject is outside this particular question.

Comment: Thank you. Seems no way but to compromise. What about the columns shinking to fit problem. What should be done. When they increase, they try to fit inside the grid width 100%